# Loop variant python

Tags: python, loops

The loop variant is supposed to be a strictly decreasing natural number, defined by the arguments in the loop. I find it a bit difficult in python since the index isn't used. For example, what is the loop variant in the below sentence?

```
P = [int(x) for x in list('{0:b}'.format(12))]
```

Comment: any pointer on the web to what you call "loop variant" ? I didn't find anything for python

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your definition is overly restrictive; not all loops have a numeric loop variant in the language they're written in, certainly not necessarily a decreasing one.  In your example, `x` is a loop variant, but not in the form you seek.

Under the covers, there is an index into the string representing the binary form of 12, and it will vary from 0 to 3.  So the loop variant, in the sense of your linked Wikipedia article, would be a function that subtracts that index from 3.

Comment: What does it mean that it's overly restrictive?

Comment: Yes that I know, but am I supposed to add index to the for loop just to be able to describe the loop variant?

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [`list-comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

And what you are doing can be written as:

```
P = []
for x in list('{0:b}'.format(12)):
    P.append(int(x))
```

It seems that the code formats the number `12` into binary (`1100`) and then each character is turned into an integer and added to `P`.

---

You can do this much easier by using the [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) builtin:

```
>>> map(int, bin(12)[2:])  # in Python 3+ call list() on the map
[1, 1, 0, 0]
```

---

`bin(12)[2:]` is much faster than `"{0:b}".format(12)` - Timing:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('bin(12)[2:]').repeat()
[0.19629462759158045, 0.15594946498989515, 0.1560687067152564]
>>> timeit.Timer('"{0:b}".format(12)').repeat()
[0.45589523752218497, 0.4375863126642727, 0.43800530974230867]
```

Comment: I don't see how `bin(12)[2:]` is easier than `'{0:b}'.format(12)`. (but it's good to give that other alternative)

Comment: Check the timing, it is between 2 and 3 times faster.

Comment: That's an excellent point! Also, you may want to add a `list()` around your map for Python3.

Comment: Who said we are using Python3?

Comment: `list(map(...))` will work for both Python2 and Python3. It's time to write code that will work on both when possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand you need to decompose.

#### Binary representation of 12

`format` allows you to give the binary representation of 12:

```
>>> '{0:b}'.format(12)
'1100'
```

You could also use `bin` but `'0b'` is append at the beginning:

```
>>> bin(12)
'0b1100'
```

However, you could write `bin(12)[2:]` (as suggested in another answer).

#### Iteration over a string

You can iterate over each character of a string using a loop by doing:

```
for x in '1100':
```

The `x` in this for loop will take the successive characters of the string: `'1', '1', '0', '0'`.

#### List comprehension

And finally, `[... for x in ...]` is a list-comprehension. That will create a new list using the for.

```
[int(x) for x in '1100']
```

is equivalent to:

```
list(map(int, '1100'))
```

and:

```
list(map(int, ['1', '1', '0', '0']))
```

or:

```
l = []
for x in '1100':
    l.append(int(x))
```

#### Loop variant?

Your question is actually: what is the loop variant here?

Well, in Python, the `for` is in fact more a `foreach`. Let's take as an example `for x in [3, 2, 10]`. `x` will successively take the values `3`, `2` and `10`.

If we want something close to the C-style for-loop:

```
// C for-loop:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

We write:

```
# Python for-loop:
for i in range(10):
```

`range(10)` returns something iterable and `i` will take the successive values given by `range`.

Back to your example, there is no "loop variant" but if you need one, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate('1100'):
    print(i, x)
```

Will give:

```
(0, '1')
(1, '1')
(2, '0')
(3, '0')
```

Comment: Using map() will actually solve my problem since I don't have to use a for loop :). Do you know the worst time complexity of map?

Comment: I think map will be faster in that specific case (not function call, only a cast to int). However, I think that list-comprehension is becoming the recommended way of doing it.